# How add dependencies to generated sources

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, maven-plugin-development

I developed my own maven plugin, which has a goal of generating sources. These sources have dependencies from my plugin code and are not compiling without it.

Is there any way to add plugin code dependencies to generated sources?
Or more precisely, is there any option beside adding plugin and dependencies separetly in pom?

Comment: Generated code should not have dependencies on the plugin because they are completely separated. If you have such things best would be separate out those dependencies into a separate artifact which can be added as a usual dependency many tools do that for example antlr plugin (antlr-runtime).. etc?

Comment: Separate the code to be shared into a new maven library project and add it as a ependency to both your plugin and the main project